# poor resolution of image and SIFT features

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, gabor-filter

I have images taken from lifelogging camera of 5MP. The image sizes are like 128x128, 125x128. I want to extract SIFT features. I am told at this poor resolution, there will be many false matches. Can someone suggest me some preprocessing or filtering techniques to enhance my SIFT performance?

Comment: You may need to use something else! The only ovbious way of improving SIFT is by taking hihger resolution images. The problem with your images is that there is not enough information for SIFT to work properly, there is nothing you can do to have more information than what you have measured

Comment: SIFT generally does not operate on images that small.  Part of it is a multi-scale feature detection algorithm and so multiple scales is designed to cover images of a fairly recent resolution. You will need to think of something else.  It also depends on what you want to do with the images. If you are using it for classification / machine learning, then it's perfectly acceptable to use those as raw inputs into a deep learning framework. You can also try a dense descriptor like HOG. In general, images of that small resolution won't perform well regardless of what techniques you use before hand.